Using access to check usb port by path fails because of port0 suffix
I want to be able to check if there is something plugged into a specific USB port in a C program. Currently I used
ls /dev/serial/by-path

to get the path to the device. I hardcoded the path in the program and use the "access" function with F_OK to check if it exists. this works fine when i tested it with one device but when i tried another device it fails because "-port0" gets added at the end of the path when this device is plugged in.
The output looks like this - device 1:
$ls /dev/serial/by-path/
platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.2:1.0

Device 2:
$ls /dev/serial/by-path/
platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.2:1.0-port0

I would like to know what causes this, if there are other variations of this and if there are other solutions besides checking both paths.
the OS is raspbian 12 running on a raspberry pi 3

So hard code the initial part and use glob.

I'm more interested in why device 1 does not show a port number. It comes from the port_number device attribute that is created by the core usbserial driver. The symbolic links are created by UDEV using the rules in "/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules".

It's possible that device 1 appears as a CDC ACM device rather than a USB serial device. You can tell by the TTY device name. USB serial devices as /dev/ttyUSB* and ACM devices appear as /dev/ttyACM*. Both types of devices are handled by the UDEV serial rules, but ACM devices do not have a port_number attribute, so won't have the -port* suffix in the symlink.

To address your other question, some USB multi-port serial devices have an internal USB hub that would appear as extra components in the path name.

i solved the problem by using a udevadm to link the two different paths to a single symbol.
i made a file named usb-serial.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/
the rules i used are
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_PATH}=="platform-xhci-hcd.1-usb-0:1:1.0", SYMLINK+="STATICUSBPORT1"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_PATH}=="platform-xhci-hcd.0-usb-0:1:1.0", SYMLINK+="STATICUSBPORT2"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_PATH}=="platform-xhci-hcd.0-usb-0:2:1.0", SYMLINK+="STATICUSBPORT3"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_PATH}=="platform-xhci-hcd.1-usb-0:2:1.0", SYMLINK+="STATICUSBPORT4"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_PATH}=="platform-xhci-hcd.1-usb-0:1:1.0-port0", SYMLINK+="STATICUSBPORT1"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_PATH}=="platform-xhci-hcd.0-usb-0:1:1.0-port0", SYMLINK+="STATICUSBPORT2"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_PATH}=="platform-xhci-hcd.0-usb-0:2:1.0-port0", SYMLINK+="STATICUSBPORT3"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_PATH}=="platform-xhci-hcd.1-usb-0:2:1.0-port0", SYMLINK+="STATICUSBPORT4"

which gives me access to the device at /dev/STATICUSBPORT# when either is plugged in.
the ID_PATH's are for the raspberry pi 5 so it might be slightly different for the raspberry pi 3.
the correct path can be found with udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep "ID_PATH="
